# trying to get 3 item rows in react native

Tags: react-native

i'm trying to render a flat list with multiple items in a 3 item, wrapping row. i have tried everyting that i know of to get it to work and i'm about to pull my hair out.

i never get anythihg other than this:  [image]

here's my card component styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
showCard: {
    borderRadius: 8,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    width: '30%',
    height: 90,
    marginBottom: 10
}
```

});

here is my container styles for this view - show list is the container for the cards:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    backgroundColor: '#f9f9f9',
},
showList: {
    padding: 15,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    backgroundColor: "#DDDDDD",
    alignContent: 'flex-start'
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Try this: set horizontal to true.

```
<Flatlist horizontal={true}></Flatlist>
```

If that doesn't work, then make sure you have flex: 1; in your showList styles and on each component wrapping showList and showCard.

Let me know if that works, otherwise, upload your code to someplace so that I can try it by my own.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you would like to create a Flatlist contains 3 columns.
You can use Flatlist prop `numColumns` according to [React-Native docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#numcolumns).

```
<FlatList 
  data={[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]}
  renderItem={({item, index}) => (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Text>{item}</Text>
    </View>
  )}
  numColumns={3}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy peasy answer use react native super grid its similar to flatlist and use maxItemsPerRow = {3}. [install this library]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-super-grid